# I want to make use two variables in next Activity but thread make it null

Tags: android

Here in my application I want to use 2 variables which I want to use in another activity. But in first activity I make thread for progress dialog bar but in thread I call one xml and get data from web service but thease two variables make null after end of thread. So please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them to the Intent that is calling the 2nd activity and then read them back:

e.g. for writing:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewTweetActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("op", "I want to transport this");
    startActivity(i);
```

and for reading back:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null) {
        String op = bundle.getString("op");
```